# Error in Running Ansible Programmatically using Python API

Tags: python, ansible

I am running below python script to run a playbook to ping a host machine. Getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ansible.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
  File "/home/tcprod/schaitanya/python_ansible/ansible.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
ImportError: No module named parsing.dataloader
```

Below is the entire script

```
from collections import namedtuple
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.vars import VariableManager
from ansible.inventory import Inventory
from ansible.playbook.play import Play
from ansible.executor.task_queue_manager import TaskQueueManager

#Initialize the objects that are needed for the play.

Options = namedtuple('Options',
                ['connection', 'module_path', 'forks', 'become',
                 'become_method', 'become_user', 'check']
            )

#initialize needed objects

variable_manager = VariableManager()
loader = DataLoader()

options = Options(
    connection='local', module_path='', forks=100, become=True,
    become_method='sudo', become_user='root', check=False)
passwords = dict(vault_pass='secret')

#create inventory and pass to variable manager

inventory = Inventory(loader=loader, variable_manager=variable_manager,
                      host_list='localhost')
variable_manager.set_inventory(inventory)

#create play with tasks

play_src = dict(
    name="ping localhost",
    hosts="localhost",
    gather_facts="no",
    tasks=[
        # installing dependencies


        dict(name="ping local host",
             action=dict(module="ping"))
           ])

play = Play().load(play_src, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader)


tqm = None
try:
    tqm = TaskQueueManager(
            inventory=inventory,
            variable_manager=variable_manager,
            loader=loader,
            options=options,
            passwords=passwords,
            stdout_callback="default",
        )
    result = tqm.run(play)
finally:
    if tqm is not None:
        tqm.cleanup()
```

How to resolve this dependency issue and make the python program work?

Comment: Don't overlap names in Python. Try to rename your script from `ansible.py` to `my_ansible.py`.

Comment: Thanks I has tried the same. But error persist

Answer (score 1):

From what I saw in my environment I got this error when the script wasn't in my root directory.

```
[root@xxx API]# ./my_ansible.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
     File "./my_ansible.py", line 5, in <module>
        from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader   
     File "/home/xxx/projects/API/ansible.py", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named parsing.dataloader
```

Once I moved it to /root - it ran fine:

```
[root@xxx ~]# ./my_ansible.py
[root@xxx ~]#
```